# How to Export a message from Queue to a XML file using IBM MQ in SPRINGBOOT

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq

I want to export a message from a queue to a XML file using IBM MQ with Spring boot and later use that XML file to put as a message into other queue.

My main objective is to move message from a dead letter queue to main queue.

Comment: Please share the code you have tried with. Stack Overflow can help you troubleshoot existing code, not write it for you. To learn more about how the community can help you, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @millerluki - I am afraid I don't have the code for exporting MQ to a XML file as I am unable to figure out how to do that using IBM MQ

Comment: MQ comes with runmqdlq and dmpmqmsg which both can accomplish what you are asking, do you have to do it with spring boot?

Comment: @JoshMc - Yes, I have to do it with Spring boot as I have an UI at front end for user to take this action.

Comment: @JoshMc - Do you have any idead on how to do that with springboot

Comment: No I do not.  Have you checked for examples?